# Reading Form Post data vs strongly typed View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a set of HTML pages containg input elements. I am in the process of converting them into `MVC Views`.

Considering performance & cleanliness of code. What is the correct way to proceed,

1. Processing Form as posted FormCollection, or
2. Create Strongly typed view to obtain input values from the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One advantage of using HTML helpers is it enables better compile-time checking of your views (allowing you to find errors at build-time instead of at runtime), and also supports richer intellisense when editing your view templates within Visual Studio.

Another advantage might be HTML helpers allows you to set any custom attributes on the HTML tag. You can do that with the helper by either passing in a dictionary or using an anonymous type like following.

```
@Html.TextArea("FirstName", Model.FirstName, new { parameter = "value" });
```

[Source 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers.aspx)

[Source 2](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/aspnet-mvc-html-helpers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an overload of TextBoxFor to set/override the input element attributes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @Value = "0", readonly="readonly" @class="cssClass"})
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks is there any significant advantage (performance) in converting all the input elements to corresponding MVC items. Why one should not go for simple form processing, using formCollection?

Comment: If you just retrieve the values in the action from Request.Form, MVC will skip the expensive reflection to bind your form elements to a model. But you don't get the nice modelbinding validation and testability

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a good question..I don't know who voted it down...there are too many strict view model evangelists in my opinion.

After Having worked with MVC for awhile my view is that for very simple things the @Html helpers work very well...however they lead to a way of thinking about the webpage/server interaction that is limiting in the long run, especially for more complicated uses. It lets you rely heavily on unobtrusive validation without having to understand how validation works on the client..this is great for the introductory programmer...as I once was...however not understanding at least the jquery validation libraries will handicap you eventually. Doing any serious web/web-application development where validation is more complicated than checking if a value is required becomes much more diffucult. In addition you are relying on Microsoft to keep their validation library in sync with the jquery validation libraries should you update them(I've ran into this issue).

In addition you need to consider what if any front-end libraries you are using and if any of them don't work well with the output of these helpers(bootstrap is one notable one). That being said form collection is faster and less restrictive...using it and the pure validation libraries will be easier and more expressive...letting you write whatever code you want. After all..how hard is it to write if(!String.IsNullorEmpty()) on the server-side or whatever type of validation you need in addition to the client.